# MySQL Phone table: How to specify a unique primary contact number per ID?

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

My table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PHONES (
    number VARCHAR(10),
    id INT,
    type VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (number),
    FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES TECHNICIANS(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I would like to specify for each id one primary contact number. I was thinking of adding a boolean column, but I can't figure out how to get it to only allow one "true" value per. id.

Comment: Hm, can you rephrase the question? How would you use it?

Comment: I have technicians, each which can have any number of phones numbers. I display a table of these technicians using AJAX, which also includes their primary contact number. I need to identify from my phones table which is their primary contact number so I can display it as a column in my HTML table. Basically trying to identify one unique phone number per technician id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically got 3 options...

1. have a boolean column but it's up to your application to maintain it
2. have an integer so you store priority (0=prime, 1=secondary, 2=tertiary,...) again you'll have to maintain it
3. Have a parent-child relationship so a parent (technician?) record has multiple child (phone number) records. The parent record would then also contain the Id of the primary child record. The only down-side is that adding records either becomes multi-step (add technician, add phone numbers, set primary phone number for technician) or you'll need a smart DAL which does it for you :)

Incidentally, I'm assuming you actually mean one primary number per TechnicianId not per PhoneId

Answer (score 2):

I'd add a foreign key from TECHNICIANS back to PHONES:

```
ALTER TABLE TECHNICIANS
  ADD COLUMN primary_number VARCHAR(10),
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (primary_number) REFERENCES PHONES (number)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

This creates a cyclical reference:  technicians references phones, and phones references technicians.  This is okay, but it requires special handling when you do things like dropping tables, restoring backups, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "loophole" in MySQL. The MySQL documentation [says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html):

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint
>   such that all values in the index must
>   be distinct. An error occurs if you
>   try to add a new row with a key value
>   that matches an existing row. This
>   constraint does not apply to NULL 
>   values except for the BDB storage
>   engine. For other engines, a UNIQUE
>   index permits multiple NULL values for
>   columns that can contain NULL.

This means that you can create a boolean column that has two values: true (or 1) and NULL.
Create a UNIQUE index over that column + your key. That allows you to only set one record to true, but any number of them can have NULL.